# Oracle 11g XE initialization on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g

I was following this tutorial:
http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.com/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

and I sucessfully installed and started oracle database. Now I wanted to connect to that DB from bash, so I found that command:

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

It asks for password, which in my case is oracle, and after I supply it, I get:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

What should I do?

**EDIT:**
I needed to add group dba and add myself to that group. However I've got other problem now. I wanted to create user, so I did:

```
CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY password
default tablespace users
temporary tablespace temp;
```

And I got: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available.
I tried: STARTUP But I got:

ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/initXE.ora'

I have '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/init.ora' file but not initXE.ora

Comment: Just `sqlplus / as sysdba` while logged as OS user which installed the DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the o/s user a member of the dba group?

Comment: I didn't have such group, but now I created it, added myself to it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new installed Oracle and you do not have initXE.ora parameter file here /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/, that means you need to create XE DB first. To do that run /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/createdb.sh script first.